# JMeter - get value from href

Tags: testing, jmeter

I am load testing an application that has a link that looks like this:

```
https://example.com/myapp/table?qid=1434e99d-5b7c-4e74-b64e-c24e9564514d&rsid=5c94ddc7-e2e4-4e69-8547-49572486f4d1
```

I need to get the dynamic value of the rsid so I can use it later in my script.

So far I have tried using the regex extractor and I am probably doing it wrong.
I have tried things like:

```
name = myvar
regular expression = rsid=(.*?) # didnt work
regular expression = <a href=".*?rsid=(.*?)"> # didnt work
Template = $1$
```

I have one extractor set up to get the csrf value and that one works as expected but that is also because the csrf value is in the page source.

The above link is NOT in the page source as far as I can see but it DOES show up when I inspect the link. I dont know if that is obfuscation or something else?

How can I extract the value of the rsid? Is the regular expression extractor the right one to use for this?
Should I be using something else?
Is it just a formula issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
rsid=[0-9A-Fa-f\-]{36}
```

the above regular expression should match a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)-like structure and your `rsid` seems to be an instance of it.

Demo:

[image]

Also be aware of the [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor), it's sufficient to specify "left" and "right" boundaries and it will extract everything in-between. In general coming up with "boundaries" is much easier than creating a regular expression, it's more readable and JMeter processes the Boundary Extractors much faster. More information: [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter)

Comment: The problem I am running into is that the rsid is not in the page source but gets computed by the javascript on the page.
I will try a beanshell preprocessor, copy/paste the code from the page source, and see if that works.